# How to run H2O Deep Water TensorFlow MOJO in Java Application?

Tags: java, tensorflow, deep-learning, h2o

I built a **H2O Deep Water model with TensorFlow backend** (following the [Deep Water Booklet](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/booklets/DeepWaterBooklet.pdf) MNIST example).

(First I did the same with a H2O GBM model to verify that it works in general without the Deep Water dependencies in my Java application. This works well.)

I downloaded my Deep Water TensorFlow model (which I built with Python):

```
modelfile = model.download_mojo(path="/h2o_testdata/generatedModels", get_genmodel_jar=True)
```

I think this step worked fine again. Now, I want to use the model zip file in my Java application:

I added the dependencies (h2o-genmodel.jar via Maven and deepwater-all.jar via copy&paste as I could not find it on Maven) to my project. **It seems like I need to add some additional dependencies or source code to add / apply the TensorFlow 'backend' (not sure what 'backend' means here as I just want to do inference in Java, not model training)?**

I instantiate the model:

```
EasyPredictModelWrapper model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(MojoModel.load("src/main/resources/generatedModels/DeepWater_model_python_1503388273301_1.zip"));
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/0s/0xdkb9n12yqdb3fs71926z3c0000gp/T/libtensorflow_jni.so147ba98b-e7e3-49bb-8d4e-e5a06efd7a66: dlopen(/private/var/folders/0s/0xdkb9n12yqdb3fs71926z3c0000gp/T/libtensorflow_jni.so147ba98b-e7e3-49bb-8d4e-e5a06efd7a66, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/folders/0s/0xdkb9n12yqdb3fs71926z3c0000gp/T/libtensorflow_jni.so147ba98b-e7e3-49bb-8d4e-e5a06efd7a66: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
    /private/var/folders/0s/0xdkb9n12yqdb3fs71926z3c0000gp/T/libtensorflow_jni.so147ba98b-e7e3-49bb-8d4e-e5a06efd7a66: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at deepwater.backends.tensorflow.LibraryLoader.loadNativeLib(LibraryLoader.java:87)
    at deepwater.backends.tensorflow.TensorflowBackend.<clinit>(TensorflowBackend.java:30)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at hex.genmodel.algos.deepwater.DeepwaterMojoModel.createDeepWaterBackend(DeepwaterMojoModel.java:96)
    at hex.genmodel.algos.deepwater.DeepwaterMojoReader.readModelData(DeepwaterMojoReader.java:31)
    at hex.genmodel.ModelMojoReader.readAll(ModelMojoReader.java:143)
    at hex.genmodel.ModelMojoReader.readFrom(ModelMojoReader.java:34)
    at hex.genmodel.MojoModel.load(MojoModel.java:35)
    at com.github.megachucky.kafka.streams.machinelearning.Kafka_Streams_Deep_Learning_H2O_MNIST.main(Kafka_Streams_Deep_Learning_H2O_MNIST.java:15)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: darwin, architecture: x86_64. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/java/README.md for possible solutions (such as building the library from source).
    at org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.load(NativeLibrary.java:66)
    at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.init(TensorFlow.java:27)
    at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.<clinit>(TensorFlow.java:31)
    at org.tensorflow.Graph.<clinit>(Graph.java:194)
    at deepwater.backends.tensorflow.models.ModelFactory.readMetaGraph(ModelFactory.java:143)
    at deepwater.backends.tensorflow.models.ModelFactory.LoadModelFromFile(ModelFactory.java:220)
    at deepwater.backends.tensorflow.TensorflowBackend.buildNet(TensorflowBackend.java:74)
    at hex.genmodel.algos.deepwater.DeepwaterMojoReader.readModelData(DeepwaterMojoReader.java:64)
    at hex.genmodel.ModelMojoReader.readAll(ModelMojoReader.java:143)
    at hex.genmodel.ModelMojoReader.readFrom(ModelMojoReader.java:34)
    at hex.genmodel.MojoModel.load(MojoModel.java:35)
    at com.github.megachucky.kafka.streams.machinelearning.Kafka_Streams_Deep_Learning_H2O_MNIST.main(Kafka_Streams_Deep_Learning_H2O_MNIST.java:15)
```

I cannot find any documentation on how to set this up, so maybe someone can help? 
Or do I need to install TensorFlow on my laptop explicitly available for the Java application, too? I thought this is not necessary with H2O because it "just generates Java code", which I can use in an application - similar to other non-DeepWater H2O models?

By the way, side question: How do I get deepwater-all.jar via Maven dependency? I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer your second question. You should never copy .jars into a Maven project. You need to [install them to you local repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) and add the dependency to your pom.xml.
(You can choose what you want as artifact and group. The vendor of the framework would be a good choice)

Comment: Yes, I agree. Just did this as quick workaround to get it running. Though, local repository is also no real option if you want to share your project (e.g. on Github), right?

Comment: You share your project on github with a maven configuration file which lets other people download their own dependency jars.

Comment: Please note that in this case you can't use a maven version since you need to use one with deepwater built in. See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Maven h2o-genmodel.jar. You have to use the h2o-genmodel.jar that comes from the H2O that you're using. The same goes for deepwater-all.jar. It has to be from the same H2O. deepwater-all.jar contains all the code you need, including the backends.

Since you used the argument get_genmodel_jar=True you downloaded that at the same time as the mojo. This is the one you must use.

Comment: Okay, this explains why mine is not working. The model download method only creates two files: DeepWater_model_python_1503483286537_1.zip and h2o-genmodel.jar.  However, deepwater-all.jar is not created. How do I create / generate this file? I also unzipped the created zip and jar to check the content. The h2o-genmodel contains some classes about the backend. But as you said, I still need the deepwater-all.jar. Thus, right now still the same exception as before, of course.

Comment: Yes, this part is not well documented. You can download it the same way you can download h2o-genmodel.jar from the running H2O app. `curl localhost:54321/3/deepwater-all.jar > deepwater-all.jar`.  You can also do `jar xvf /opt/h2o.jar www/3/deepwater-all.jar` to get it out into a `www/3` directory.

Comment: Yeah, the inconsistency and incompleteness of H2O docs / booklets / github examples is really a big problem for beginners like me, unfortunately. Anyway, I still have the same problem after using the correct JARs: "Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: darwin, architecture: x86_64." Is there a need for a local TensorFlow installation or any additional dependency? Can you maybe share with me a working Java example / project and the corresponding H2O Deep Water JARs which you created? (the issue is with Deep Water - a standard GBM model works well the same way)

Comment: Since Deepwater is built for Ubuntu Linux only we don't have a version for Macintosh (i.e., darwin). You can run the CPU-only docker image on the Mac, and what I talked about above has to be run within the docker image. You also have to run the resulting Java code within the docker image. It will not run on your Mac since it contains code that is compiled for and can only be run in Ubuntu 16.04 Linux. Unfortunately there are quite a few moving parts here. This is why we provide the docker images where everything has been installed for you.

Comment: Thanks for clarification (again) :-) I will try it out within the Docker instance. I assume it will work then...